# Localizing a string with a tag inside

Tags: php, localization

I have the following sting that I need to localize for translation

```
<?php echo 'Click <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">here</a> to go and wacth the video.' ?>
```

My problem is the `<a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">here</a>` part in the middle of the sentence. I did try to break it up like this

```
<?php printf(__('Click %s to go and wacth the video.', 'pietergoosen'), '<a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">here</a>'); ?>
```

This works, but the word `here` inside the `<a>` tag then can't be translated.

Any suggestions how this can be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the tag into two separate strings:

```
printf(__('Click %shere%s to go and wacth the video.', 'pietergoosen'), '<a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">', '</a>');
```